# How to install PyGLEW in mac?

Tags: python, macos, configuration, installation, package

I've downloaded PyGLEW from [this site](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Calle_Lejdfors/pygpu/#PyGLEW) to work with PyGPU. But I'm not sure how to install it.

I tried to install it with the usual technique. But it didn't work out.

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running install_data
error: can't copy 'pyglew.so': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

I couldn't install it pip either

```
sudo pip install pyglew
...
No matching distribution found for pyglew
```

Is there any other way to install PyGLEW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current directory should be the downloaded folder. After navigating to this directory, run `python setup.py build` followed by `python setup.py install`.